# Cloudant NoSql Bluemix Content type error : bad_content_type

Tags: json, zend-framework, curl, cloudant, ibm-cloud

Has anyone encountered this error ? I have searched for the response on the internet, even wrote to IBM Cloudant support but nothing. 
Yesterday it was working alright but now it's not working. I am using Zend Framework 1.12 and `Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl()` function to send `POST` to the Cloudant database. I have an object :

**PART OF OBJECT**

```
$obj = 
    {"articles":[
        {
        "_id":"1100_20144071226",
        "id":"1100_20144071226",
        "title":"BLA BL BADASDSDDAS A BLA Native Advertising Shakes Up Agency And Brand Ecosystem",
        "img":"http:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/static.mediapost.com\/publications\/images\/mp-logo-fb.jpg",
        "titleOrg":null,
        "description":"Brands such as <i class=\"highlight\">Pepsi<\/i>, Logitech,SONY, FOX, CBS, TiVo, Timberland, US Gov\'t and many more find complete, seamless satisfacting with HITVIEWS\' approach."
        },
    etc etc ... 
    ]
```

So i want to send it to curl with function :

```
$curl = new Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl();
    $client = new Zend_Http_Client( $this->uri."/".$db );
    $client->setAdapter( $curl );
    $client->setMethod( Zend_Http_Client::POST );
    $client->setParameterPost("_id", $obj['id']);
    $client->setParameterPost($obj);
    $client->setHeaders('Content-type' ,'application/json');
return print $response = $client->request()->getBody();
```

The response i'm getting is  :

> "error":"bad_content_type","reason":"Content-Type must be
>   application/json"

Has anyone had this kind of problem with Cloudant lately (yesterday it was working fine)? Am I setting correctly header's `Content-Type` for `application/json`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are setting the header correctly... My guess is that the object you are posting isn't JSON.  Try converting `$obj` to JSON.

Use the following instead of `$client->setParameterPost($obj);`

```
$client->setRawData(json.dumps($obj), 'application/json')
```

Comment: Will try, when I come home.. Hmm although I think it was earlier setRawData().. Thanks :-)

Comment: Yup, that was the problem, i puted like this 
`$client->setRawData(Zend_Json_Encoder::encode($obj));`
And it's inserting documents :) 
Thanks a bunch man :) What-a mistek-a to make-a :)